# spring static is not loading until restart application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, static

I'm using Spring framework on maven with Java 17 and intelliJ, and I have few endpoint to get the image from the server and they all work, as the title say I have problem after i upload image to static/image
I try to get it but I get white label error, and only after restart the server I can get access to the image , I've tried to this:

1. adding dev tools again (I already had).
2. adding <configuration> <addResources>true</addResources> </configuration>
3. tried to change the application.properties with no success.

> [this is the response from the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP06m.png)

> [response when I try to get it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylGEx.png)

> [image on static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Ldl.png)

> [after restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/690Eo.png)

How I can fix this ? thanks for every one and have a good day